# Show content of subdomain from specific menu-item?

Tags: menus, links

If have a site with menu that has links that looks something like this:

```
domain.com?page=3
domain.com?page=35
domain.com?page=3
```

I want wordpress to show content of shop.domain.com when user clicks on a specific menu-item (`maybe domain.com?page=35`). What would be the sufficient way to do this? Is this possible in Wordpress itself or would I have to resolve to using htaccess?

Comment: What do you mean by "show the content"? Import the content into the WordPress site or redirect to the target site?

Comment: Your clarification is confusing. And "ordinary redirect" would change the address in the address bar.

Comment: Ok. I'll try once more... I mean that it should redirect to shop.domain.com without the adress in the adress-bar changing.